# Приложение для работы с вконтакте

Tags: html, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я много слушаю музыку с ноутбука (vk), поэтому всегда хотел создать приложение, которое автоматически (горячие клавиши) переключает мне музыку на следующую, если я не хочу сейчас слушать эту, и назад, если я случайно нажал хоткей или хочу переслушать ещё раз.

Сейчас я посмотрел немного и вижу, что VK API даёт доступ к базе данных и ничего похожего с моей задумкой. Кстати, когда я на каком-то ЯП биндил горячие клавиши (дело было на Windows), то без активного окна приложения (консоли) они не работали. Нужно было переключать на консоль и нажимать их. Это проблема, но она, скорее всего, решается легко, просто я не знаю как.

Я не могу понять толком как это сделать, как в общем работать с элементами HTML **стороннего** сайта через приложение. Что для этого нужно и т. п.. Это и есть вопрос.

P.S. Не уверен, как точно работают автореги почт, но, возможно, это примерно так же. Они же получают капчу, передают её в приложение и регистрируют аккаунты, заполняя поля (хотя, возможно, это делается с помощью запросов и пример ни к чему).

Comment: Насколько я знаю, интерфейс взаимодействия с плеером ВК реализован на стороне клиента с помощью `JavaScript`. В таком случае Вам может помочь `Selenium`, но это плохой подход. Я бы на Вашем месте воспользовался каким-либо ЯП и реализовал бы собственный интерфейс, используя любую библиотеку для получение аудиозаписей из ВК. Например, в `Python` для этого есть библиотекой [vk_api](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).